# type function on class with metaclass

Tags: python, metaclass

```
class ParamMeta(type):
  def __str__(self):
    return self.__name__


class Param(object):
  __metaclass__=ParamMeta

class SomeParam(Param):
  pass
```

What I want is for:

```
type(SomeParam)==Param
```

How do I achieve this?

**Update**: what do I need to change to have the desired behavior?

**Update2**: For posterity: this question is totally and utterly bogus. Please pretend you haven't seen it ;)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this, what is your usecase? **Why** does `type(SomeParam)` need to be the base class, instead of the `ParamMeta` metatype? What happens if there are *multiple* base classes?

Comment: I want to be able the have simple and expressive assert statements e.g. assert type(SomeParam)==Param

Comment: No, that is not a use case. That is not a reason to subvert the Python class and type system. Most of all, that is not a reason at all.

Comment: Call it what you want, that's what I want.

Comment: I am trying to help you achieve your goals here. What you want here may well be impossible. But if you give us the underlying reasons then we can perhaps help you find what *can* be done.

Comment: The most common reason to want to do `type(Something) == OtherType` is instance type checking for subclasses, which is what `isinstance()` gives you, hence my answer.

Comment: Specifically: Why do you want **type()** to do that, rather than a different function?

Comment: `isinstance` would be OK too. But it doesn't work as currently implemented.

Comment: Then my question becomes: why **isinstance()**? That too does something completely different from what you want to do. Why do you want to shoehorn operation X into a function that does Y, rather than using a function that just does X?

Comment: That's why I wanted `type`.  `type([])==list`.  `SomeParam` is of type `Param`

Comment: @jldupont `SomeParam` is of type `ParamMeta`, not `Param`. Inheriting from a class doesn't make it a type of that class. You should read this answer about metaclasses: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/2032433

Comment: No, `SomeParam` is *not* of type `Param`. You just confirmed my suspicion that this question is based on a big misunderstanding. Read my answer again. I attempted to address this misconception.

Comment: I understand all of this!!! I just want a solution to coerce this whole thing to work with the `type` function!

Comment: @jldupont: There is no way to coerce the `type` function. We want you to tells us **what problem you are trying to solve**; there probably is no need to keep walking into this wall again and again.

Comment: @jldupont: `issubclass(SomeParam, Param)` will return `True`. `isinstance(SomeParam(), Param)` returns `True`, but neither of those are what you want?

Comment: @jldupont The reason we want to know what you're *really* trying to do is because this screams "[XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)" at 120 dB. Whatever your problem is, I am confident that there is a good solution that does not involve what the text of your question is demanding.

Comment: Guys, 1M apologies. I got my head completely screwed up this morning. I understand now what you were trying to say: type(SomeParam)!=Param.  How do I delete this abomination of a question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of the `SomeParam` class object is not `Param`, it's `ParamMeta`, and `type()` correctly reports that. You're confusing the is-a and inherits-from relationships. A `SomeParam` *instance* is-a `Param`. The `SomeParam` class object, on the other hand, *inherits* from the `Param` class object, but it is not an *value of type* `Param`.

For subclass relationships, there is the builtin `issubclass()`, which is the analogue of `isinstance` for is-a relationships: `issubclass(SomeParam, Param)` is true.

Edit: There is nothing you can do to achieve `type(SomeParam)` returning `Param`, except of course shadowing the name `type` with a hand-written function that returns the base class (which would be extremely misleading and bad style).

Comment: Exactly what my answer tried to address, but got downvoted for. :-)

Comment: Please reread the question:  I want a solution so that I have 'type(SomeParam)==Param'.  I don't need the explanation as to why this doesn't work as described here.

Comment: @jldupont That's like asking for `print(x)` to increment `x`. It is wrong and does not make sense. You can make define a function that gives you the/a superclass and you can test whether a something is a subclass of something else, but both operations are completely different from what `type()` does.

Comment: @jldupont Please reread the answer. He's trying to explain why what you're asking is not possible.